# How to do select and delete operation in hibernate relation

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Below is my code have one-to-many relation that is between parent and student.
My requirement is:

1. When I give a student's `class_name` then respective parents *information should be display*
2. If I enter reference `id` of parent to delete then respective child of that parent should *deleted*

i have left coding in test classes because i dont know how to write query to get out like example select operation. please let me know and if there is any error in DTO classes

#### `select` operation query:

```
select  pt.P_MOBILE,pt.P_EMAIL,st.S_FIRSTNAME,st.REF_ID  
from parent_info pt join student_info st on pt.REF_ID = st.REF_ID 
where st.S_CLASS_TO_JOIN= ?;
```

#### Parent class:

```
@Table(name = "parent_info")
public class ParentDTO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private int p_id;

    @Column(name = "P_NAME")
    private String p_name;

    @Column(name = "P_PHONE")
    private String p_phone;

    @Column(name = "P_EMAIL")
    private String p_email;

    @Column(name = "REF_ID")
    private String ref_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")

    private List<StudentDTO> students;

    //getters and setters

}
```

#### Student class:

```
@Table(name = "student_info")
public class StudentDTO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "S_ID")
    private int s_id;

    @Column(name = "S_NAME")
    private String s_name;

    @Column(name = "S_PHONE")
    private String s_phone;

    @Column(name = "S_EMAIL")
    private String s_email;

    @Column(name = "REF_ID")
    private String ref_id;

    @Column(name = "S_CLASS_NAME")
    private String s_class_name;        

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private ParentDTO parent;           

    //getters and settrs    
}
```

**Test class to select query:**
Tried this now: unexpected token: th near line 1, column 90 [select s from com.pradeepdemo.StudentDTO s join fetch s.parent  where s.s_class_name = 10th]

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<StudentDTO> groupList = null;
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();         
        Query query = session.createQuery("select s from StudentDTO s join fetch s.parent  where s.s_class_name = 10th");
        groupList = query.list();           
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

}

**Test class to delete query:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();    
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect this code to do? It just opens a transaction and commits it without doing anything inside.

Comment: read my question completely

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve your requirements, and you need to specify for the list of parents the "mappedBy" attribute

Comment: i had executed in jdbc please let me know how to do in hibernate am new to hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Try to read examples on this link to have an idea about how to use HQL:
[Hibernate - Query Language](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) & [Hibernate Query examples (HQL)](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/)

**EDIT 1**

As you can read  in Docs : [Forms of join syntax](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms)

> HQL supports two forms of association joining: implicit and explicit.

Comment: I know to execute queries on single table if possible can you tell me how to solve that queries

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your model classes with @Entity everything should sort itself out. Hibernate is supposed to work the basic CRUD operations on its own, without having to write HQL.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm

Comment: I know those things i followed java brains if possible can you tell me how to solve that queires

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

First Mapping between two entities like below

**Parent**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="PARENT")
    public class ParentDTO {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Long parentId;

        @Column(name="firstname")
        private String parentName;  

        @Column(name="ParentPhone")
        private Long parentPhone;

        @Column(name="ParentEMail")
        private String parentEMail;


        @Column(name="ReferenceID")
        private String referenceID;


        @OneToOne(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Student student;


        public ParentDTO() {

        }


        public ParentDTO(Long parentId, String parentName, Long parentPhone,
                String parentEMail, String referenceID, Student student) {
            super();
            this.parentId = parentId;
            this.parentName = parentName;
            this.parentPhone = parentPhone;
            this.parentEMail = parentEMail;
            this.referenceID = referenceID;
            this.student = student;
        }
        //getters and setters   
    }
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class StudentDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="parent"))

    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "StudentName")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "StudentClass")
    private int studentClass;

    @Column(name = "ReferenceID")
    private String referenceID;


    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ParentDTO parent;


    public Student() {

    }


    public Student(Long id, String studentName, int studentClass,
            String referenceID, ParentDTO parent) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentClass = studentClass;
        this.referenceID = referenceID;
        this.parent = parent;
    }    
    //getters and setters       
}
```

**Select query**

```
public void select()
    {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            String hql = "from ParentDTO as p, StudentDTO as s where p.referenceID=s.referenceID and s.referenceID='ReferencID-1'";
            List<?> list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
                ParentDTO parent = (ParentDTO)row[0];
                Student student = (Student)row[1];
                System.out.println(parent.getParentEMail());
                System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
            }   

            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
```